# RangeS-U and U locks at the same time and on the same resource

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock, sql-server-profiler

I'm working with some stored procedure and deadlock situation.

I've been using SQL Server Profiler and get some information about the deadlock from 'Deadlock graph' event in form of the .xdl file.
Below content of that file.

I've just cleared some informations about the statement.The statement marked as `<executionStack>` in the .xdl was something like this (for both processes the same statement):

```
SELECT SomeColumn, SomeColumn2
FROM SomeTable WITH (UPDLOCK)
INNER JOIN SomeTable2 ON SomeTable.SomeTable2ID = SomeTable2.SomeTable2ID
INNER JOIN SomeTable3 ON SomeTable2.SomeTable3ID = SomeTable3.SomeTable3ID
WHERE SomeColumn = @Something AND SomeColumn2 = @Something2
```

And the content of the .xdl file:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="processc19dc8">
  <process-list>
   <process id="processc19dc8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594042646528 (8194443284a0)" waittime="1541" ownerId="21923027" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-07-02T18:03:42.260" XDES="0x80051950" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="2" kpid="2712" status="suspended" spid="54" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2013-07-02T18:03:42.260" lastbatchcompleted="2013-07-02T18:03:42.260" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="XXX" hostpid="2148" loginname="XXX" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="21923027" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    ...
   </process>
   <process id="processc4d048" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594042646528 (a0c936a3c965)" waittime="1541" ownerId="21923023" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-07-02T18:03:42.260" XDES="0x80049800" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="4" kpid="2492" status="suspended" spid="53" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2013-07-02T18:03:42.260" lastbatchcompleted="2013-07-02T18:03:42.260" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="XXX" hostpid="2148" loginname="XXX" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="21923023" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   ...
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594042646528" dbid="5" objectname="dbo.SomeTable" indexname="PK_SomeTable" id="lock83d99200" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594042646528">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processc4d048" mode="RangeS-U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processc19dc8" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594042646528" dbid="5" objectname="dbo.SomeTable" indexname="PK_SomeTable" id="lock89b52900" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594042646528">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processc19dc8" mode="U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processc4d048" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

So it looks like the first process owns a resource with `mode=U`, and the second owns the same resource with `mode=RangeS-U`.

How it is possible if these two modes are not compatible with each other (according to the [compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396.aspx))?

Comment: They are not exactly the same resource. The locks are on two distinct keys, KEY: 5:72057594042646528 (8194443284a0) and KEY: 5:72057594042646528 (a0c936a3c965)

Comment: I've already changed the code of that stored procedure, so that the deadlock no longer occurs. But you're right, I did not notice that.